# How to change the color of the active / selected tab?

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

I want the color to be the default gray color when the tab is not selected but to be my `tabBarColor` color when the tab is selected. I could not find a way to change the color of the title in the tab bar.

How can I do that?

This is my code:

```js
Home:{
  screen: TabNavigator({
   Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
        <Ionicons
        name={focused ? 'ios-home' : 'ios-home-outline'}
        size={26}
        style={{ color: focused ? `${tabBarColor}` : tintColor}}
        />
      ),
      //headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#553A91"},
      //headerTitleStyle: {color: "#FFFFFF"},
      header: null,
    }),
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Profile',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
        <Ionicons
        name={focused ? 'ios-people' : 'ios-people-outline'}
        size={26}
        style={{ color: focused ? `${tabBarColor}` : tintColor }}
        />
      ),
      //headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#553A91"},
      //headerTitleStyle: {color: "#FFFFFF"},
      header: null,
    }),
  },
}),
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [**TabNavigator Docs**](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html), it is clearly indicated that you need to use `activeTintColor`

> `activeTintColor`: label and icon color of the active tab

Example:

```
const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
  },
}, {
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            ...
        }
  }),
  tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#ffffff',
  },
});
```

Comment: Where should I add the tabBarOptions? I tried adding it but it won't work :(

Comment: It pretty sure it can go in `navigationOptions` in parallel with `title`, `tabBarIcon`... etc. Or same as my example but under what is called `tabBarOptions` and not `navigationOptions`

Comment: what if i want to *differentiate* label and icon color??

Answer (score 1):

1. Define variable route,
2. Add props listeners to each <Tab.Screen>,
3. Use variable route for change color of tabBarLabel.

Example :

```
const [route, setRoute] = useState('home');
 

        <Tab.Navigator>
           <Tab.Screen listeners={{
                  tabPress: (e) => {
                    setRoute('home');
                  },
                }}
                options={{
                  tabBarLabel: (
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        color: route === 'home' ? 'ACTIVE_COLOR' : 'INACTIVE_COLOR',
                      }}>
                      home
                    </Text>
                  ) />
    
    <Tab.Screen listeners={{
                  tabPress: (e) => {
                    setRoute('profile');
                  },
                }}
                options={{
                  tabBarLabel: (
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        color: route === 'profile' ? 'ACTIVE_COLOR' : 'INACTIVE_COLOR',
                      }}>
                      profile
                    </Text>
                  ) />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

I hope I was able to help you